# Getting exit status of command executed using exec of Net::SSH::Expect

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, expect

I am running the following script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Expect;


my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(host=>"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",password=>"xxxxxxx", user=>"root" ,timeout=>3  );

$ssh->login();
$ssh->exec("stty -echo");

print "Connection Established\n";

my ($out) = $ssh->exec("rpm -ivh xxx");
print "\n\nOUTPUT: $out\n";


#$ssh->send("echo $?");
($out) = ($ssh->get_expect())->exitstatus();

print "\n\nEXIT STATUS: $out\n";
```

**Running this, I am not able to get the exit status of the "rpm -ivh ..." command that I executed.**

I am new to Perl, please help me out with this.

Comment: Why the parenthesis around ($out)? The documentation does not have these. (https://metacpan.org/release/Net-SSH-Expect)

Also, you can remove the -w flag in the first line if you have "use warnings".

Comment: @davewood. True, you should try `$out = $ssh->exec("rpm -ivh xxx");` ... but this would not solve your desire for `$?`, nor the potential issues with the remote prompt and/or prompt_command.

Answer (score 2):

This is as expected regarding `$?` behaviour.

The `Net::SSH::Expect` module is nothing more than *Expect* way of handling remote command execution: you can only rely on the command output, not the underlying exit code value given to the remote shell.

You can either:

- modify your remotely executed command to somehow show/return some string related to the command exit status:
  ex: `rpm -ivh xxx && echo OK`),
- use an SSH module less text-output oriented like **`Net::OpenSSH`**. It is a module with nice features, close to the SSH protocol and actively maintained.

  - From **`Net::OpenSSH`** documentation:

    > $ssh->system(\%opts, @cmd)

    *Runs the command @cmd on the remote machine. Returns true on sucess, undef otherwise*.

    *The error status is set to* OSSH_SLAVE_CMD_FAILED *when the remote command exits with a  non zero code (the code is available from `$?`, see "`$?`" in perlvar)*.
  - Using **`Net::OpenSSH`**:

    ```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Net::OpenSSH;
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new( "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
                                 user    => "root" ,
                                 passwd  => "xxxxxxx", 
                                 timeout => 3, 
                               );

    if ($ssh) {
         print "Connection Established\n";

         my $out = $ssh->capture("rpm -ivh xxx");
         print "\n\nOUTPUT: $out\n";
         print "\n\nEXIT STATUS: $?\n";
    }
    ```